# Creating rectangular graphic on single mouse click using ArcGIS API for Silverlight?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, graphics

I'm using Silverlight plugin 5.1.3 and I'm trying to create a rectangular polygon graphic based on a mappoint.  For simplicity reasons, lets assume the maps spatial reference is Web Mercator WGS84 and the rectangle is 1 Meter by 2 Meters.

How can I go about this?

Comment: did you mean Web Mercator as the coordinate system?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Web Mercator WGS84

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar. What I did was:

1. Created a  in xaml and linked its Points value to a PointCollection variable in my model and the Visibility with another one.
2. Then at the `mouseclickevent`, I get the `e.GetPosition` which gives you screen coordinates of you mouse.

From here, you can calculate your coners in screen coordinates, but I needed them in my coordinate system. So I did:

3. Via `mainpage.ScreenToMap(screenPoint)` you can convert it to a MapPoint with a specific spatial reference system.
4. From this point, you can calculate your corners (easier with projected reference system so you could use meters)
5. Save you corners as screen points in the `System.Windows.Media.PointCollection` variable and control the visibilty of your polygon with the visibility variable.

Comment: `Created a in xaml and linked its Points` created a what? the sentence doesn't make sense